# C# Tile class NullException

Tags: c#, xna

I'm working on a tile game, but I ran into a big problem.
The idea is that if a tile is selected it turns red and a few tiles surounded turn blue. if you click one of the blue ones the unit of the slected one is transported to that one , but every time a do this my selected tile has a NullException . I can use the Tile itself, but non of the values or voids  it contains which always return null. I'd be very thankfull if someone could pinpoint the problem

Code in order of likelyhood of problem

Part of Update():

```
 while (j < baseLayer.MapDimensions.Y)
        {
            while (i < baseLayer.MapDimensions.X)
            {
                if (moveToMap[i, j] && standardCheck.Click(new Rectangle(i * 100, j * 100, 100, 100), mouseState, prevMouseState))
                {

                    tileArray[i, j].changeColor = Color.Gold;
                    tileArray[i, j].MoveTo(tileArray[(int)selectedTile.X, (int)selectedTile.Y].Position,
                       tileArray[(int)selectedTile.X, (int)selectedTile.Y].getUnit);// problem occors here
```

//problem occurres here

```
                }
                else
                {
                    tileArray[i, j].Checkclick(mouseState, prevMouseState, relativeMousePosition);
                    if (tileArray[i, j].ReturnIfSelected)
                    {
                        selectedTile = new Vector2(i, j);
                    }
                    else if (selectedTile == new Vector2(i, j))
                        selectedTile = new Vector2(200, 200);

                }
                i++;

            }
            i = 0;
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
```

Tile class

```
    public Unit unit  = new Unit();
    public Unit Building = new Unit();
    public Unit getUnit
        {
        get { return unit; }
        }


    public Color tileColor = Color.White;
    public Vector2 position;
    public Vector2 drawPosition;


    public int[] map { set; get; } = new int[4];
    public bool selected = false;
           public void LoadContent(Vector2 _position ,int[,,] _map)
    {

    }
    public void Checkclick(MouseState mS, MouseState prevMS,Vector2 matrixPosition)
    {

        }
    }
    public bool checkifselectable()
    {

    }
    public void Update(int[,,] _map)
    {
        unit.Reset();
    }
    public void MoveTo(Vector2 oldTile,Unit _unit)
    {
        int change = 0;
        if (oldTile.X - position.X != 0)
           change = (int)(oldTile.X - position.X);
        if (oldTile.Y - position.Y !=0)
            change = (int)(oldTile.Y - position.Y);
        unit = _unit;
        map[2] = _unit.ID;
        if (change>= 0)
        unit.RemainingMoveSpeed = change;
        if (change < 0)
            unit.RemainingMoveSpeed = -change;
    }
```

Thanks already for your time

The Young Programmer

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to find out **exactly** which line is throwing the exception? Knowing this will take you a long way to the solution.

Comment: It's in there but behind some other code I made it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have NullReferenceException. In this case, this exception is thrown when there is an attempt to dereference a null object reference. This might help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: Yep, but the problem being I don't know how i got there  or how to fix it now.